# NativeScript, Android - connection to localhost fails

Tags: android, node.js, http, localhost, nativescript

I have problem with connecting to localhost on my android emulator.
I have created rest node server:

```
...
app.listen(80, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 80!'))
```

when I try to connect to it with NativeScript:

```
this.http.get("10.0.2.2/api/categories")
        .map(function (result) { return result.json(); })
        .subscribe(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

I get:

```
System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 10.0.2.2/api/categories
System.err:     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:590)
System.err:     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:487)
System.err:     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:436)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(Async.java:512)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$Http$1.run(Async.java:482)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
System.err:     at org.nativescript.widgets.Async$PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(Async.java:52)
System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 200  for URL: null
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried localhost/api/categories?

Comment: make sure to have `usesClearTextTraffic` enabled:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56815634/why-my-emulator-doesnt-work-with-nativescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.http.get("http://10.0.2.2/api/categories")
        .map(function (result) { return result.json(); })
        .subscribe(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```