# Why my Emulator doesn't work with NativeScript?

Tags: android, angular, android-emulator, nativescript, json-server

I have uploaded my project here https://github.com/rezaee/conFusion, but when I try to run it using `tns run android --device Pixel_2_API_29` it opens my emulator but show this error message on it's screen:

`Error:0-Unknown Error Http failure response for https://10.0.2.2`

I also tried the following lines as well but all gives the same error:

```
export const baseURL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/";
export const baseURL = "http://192.168.1.5:3000/";
export const baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/";
```

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: `localhost` will not work for sure as Emulator runs on it's own context, more like a separate device. `http://10.0.2.2:3000` - is it a public IP, make sure it's accessible in browser / rest client in first place, it doesn't look like from my end.

Comment: @Manoj: It gives me `This site can’t be reached 10.0.2.2 took too long to respond.`

Comment: @Manoj: I found it from here https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: May I know what exactly you are trying to do here, why you would hit that IP? If you trying to access any REST APIs hosted on your local machine Or public server, it should be IP of that machine.

Comment: @Manoj: I have a json-server that when I run it it watches on `localhost:3000/`. So I like to point the emulator to watch that address and shows the contents of there too.

Comment: I have `localhost:3000/dishes` for example. Or `localhost:3000/images`, etc. I like to say to the emulator that load those contents.

Comment: Then find the local IP on your machine where you are running the JSON server. On Mac you may find it in Network Preferences.

Comment: @Manoj: I have Windows10 and when I run `ipconfig` it shows me `Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1`, `Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8: and `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi` that each of them has a local IP address.

Comment: I used `192.168.1.5` that is for `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi` but didn't work and gives me the same error message.

Comment: I tried all the three local IP addresses but none of them worked!

Comment: Unless you are able to access the APIs with IP (for e.g http://192.168.1.5:3000/dishes) at least within a browser on your machine / Rest Client, you are pointing to wrong IP.  This has nothing to do with your Android Emulator or NativeScript. I'm not a Windows user, hence not sure where you could find right IP. You may just google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one month of trying, I found the following answer on the NativeScript's github:

Test on API29 and the issue is that you are probably missing the `cleartext` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Set it here: `your-application/app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

Setting `android:usesCleartextTraffic` in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@drawable/opportuity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
          android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```